# How to use jquery.initialize Plugin on IE 9

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery Intialize Plugin (https://github.com/timpler/jquery.initialize) which works fine on modern browser.

Unfortunately I have to support the Internet Explorer 9/10 where the jquery.initialize Plugin not works. In the readme of the Intialize Plugin there is a note for IE9 and IE10:

> Note: To make it work on IE9 and IE10 you'll need to add MutationObserver polyfill - like ones here: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs

In the demo of the Intialize Plugin there is another note in the test.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jquery.initialize test</title>
    <!-- Load MutationObserver and WeakMap polyfill for IE9 and 10 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.initialize.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've included the MutationObserver.js and WeakMap.js in the test.html but it still does not work in IE9 :-(

Comment: Your link to MutationObserver does not mention compatibility with IE9 but with IE10 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/161), it seems you will need to use version 0.5.2 of the webcomponents.js which is available here:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/webcomponentsjs/0.5.2

Comment: Thank you very much! I´ve included the `webcomponents-lite.min.js` file from your link and it works in IE9/10